# Gmaps4rails : auto-ajust fails after call to replace_markers()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

When using Gmaps4Rails, an asynchronous call to replace_markers() does update the markers, but the zoom level and center remain the same.

Any way to force an update or have gmaps4rails do it automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the gem.

It should be fixed now in [gmaps4rails 0.6.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails/versions/0.6.1)

Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick bugfix. However, it's still not working : the map zoom is correctly updated, but the previously displayed markers are still taken into account for calculating the autozoom, unless the map is fully reloaded.

Comment: You were right, it's fixed in 0.6.4 :) I added another option: auto_zoom to set automatically or not the zoom level when using auto_adjust